# pass an array of object to $stateParams value using angular-ui-router in readable format

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to make my report parameter part of the url, but since the model is an array of object [{}, {}], when I pass this to the stateParam, the URL gets encoded (replaces [, { etc with digits) and hence are no more readable.

Exa.

I have a form something like this:

```
$scope.models = [{}, {}];

<div classs="" ng-repeat="each_model in models"> 
 <input class="" model="each_model.name"> Name
 <input class="" model="each_model.class"> Class
 <input class="" model="each_model.city"> City
</div>
```

Currently I am passing $scope.models to $stateParams, by passing complete data to parameters:

```
$state.go('report', {parameters: models});
```

==my app.js

```
.state('report', {
    url: '/report?parameters',
    templateUrl: 'views/class_report.html',
})
```

How can I pass the data to the URL, so that its readable?

Answer (score 0):

Just check what you try to put into "parameters".

```
$state.go('class_report', {parameters: models});
```

expect object inside **models**

and in yours app.js

```
.state('report', {
    url: '/report:parameters',
    templateUrl: 'views/class_report.html',
    params: {
              parameters: "some defaulr"
            }
   })
```

Comment: I think I am already doing this, but since modal is an object it encodes when user navigates the url www.example.com/?parameters=[{a:1,b:test},{a:3,b:test1}]   to www.example.com/?parameters%3D%5B%7Ba%3A1%2Cb%3Atest%7D%2C%7Ba%3A3%2Cb%3Atest1%7D%5D

Comment: Also I want the parameters to be visible on URL.